# Old questions still not answered, did they figure it out?

Tags: discussion

**Introduction:**

I recently came across a post that was very interesting to me because it was dealing with things I'm in the middle of using right now for my current application e.g., Java Script Engine and the use of JavaScript and Java together. This has been a difficult project for me because the issues I've run into are so specific i.e., perhaps people aren't using this stuff everyday, and so finding questions with answers has been hard to come by.

So I found the post [Clone Entire JavaScript ScriptEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116120/clone-entire-javascript-scriptengine?rq=1) and thought, "*wow*" that could really come in handy for my project. But there is no answer for it (other than someone simply stating what the error code meant which he really already stated in his question). I then noticed this was for his PhD and *was asked over two years ago* so he must have come up with a solution (maybe it was the alternative solution he mentioned in his question that he could do as a backup but seemed reluctant to use).

**Queston:**

Is there a way for someone with a low reputation (i.e., I cannot comment on the post) to get into contact with someone from the Stack? I know we don't want pesky emails or harassment but it would be nice if I could shot him an message asking what he did two years ago to solve his problem.

Any advice on when I come across a rare question that is exactly what I'm looking for but it is old, (outdated?), and unanswered?

Comment: See [How do I contact other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users).

Comment: Interesting question. I've put a bounty on it to bring it back into focus. Also noteworthy: the OP's last visit was "yesterday", and it appears he's still quite active. So possibly he can answer his own question by now.

Comment: If you look at the 50 bounty question comment, op has resolved to a javascriopt solution